# uinavigationcontroller updating previous view when popping back

Tags: button, uinavigationcontroller, reload, back

I have a UINavigationController and I go from Level1 to Level2 where I select a row/item ; and then I go back using the back button - BUT - in my level 1 I was displaying a default selection (which I changed by going to Level2 and select something else) - and my level 1 does not change at all so I guess that the viewDidLoad is not called again... how do I force it to reload?

Thanks a lot

Cheers
geebee

EDIT1:
i know you are right but it didn't work - I was aksing myself if it has to do with all the stuff about re-usable cells and so it does not reload... is that possible? any more ideas

EDIT2:
in fact, it didn't work means that I copied all the code (I moved it in fact) from didLoad to viewWillAppear - was that the right thing to do?
or should have tried to update my nsmutablearray at the right place?
Thanks. Cheers

edit 3: in fact, putting some more flags/messages in my code to understand what is going on, although viewWillAppear is called when re-displayed, the visible cells are not "repainted/refreshed". as such if I scroll down then up, magically the changes are working and appear BUT I would like this to happen right from the start. any idea please help. thanks

Comment: solved! thanks
I added a [self.tableView reloadData]; in the viewWillAppear method!

Comment: as @nanshi comment, viewWillAppear is not called in iOS4.3, how did you solve that problem?

Answer (score 3):

`-viewDidLoad` is called only once during the lifetime of a UIViewController.  It is called right after the view controller's view is requested, such as by accessing its `view` property.  Therefore, in your case you want to put your reloading code in `-viewWillAppear:`.  This method is called every time your view controller's view is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your updating code to controller's `-viewWillAppear:` method

Answer (score 0):

But -viewWillAppear is not called in ios 4.3, it does get called in ios 5.0 and up